# Macbook auto adjusts gamma in game

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm playing Starcraft 2, and like playing it on high gamma. However, when I set the gamma in the setting, after a couple of second the graphics become very dark again. It is not a problem of the game, since the screen is dark but the gamma slider did not move in the game. And when I just click (not adjust) the gamma slider, it goes back to what it should be for a second, but then it auto-darkens again.

Is this some OSX setting? Could it be related to the dual GPU's in the macbook pro?

Comment: Do you see the same effect in any other games?

Comment: Are you sure it adjusts gamma, or brightness? The two are not equal. BTW, *lower* gamma would normally be considered 'brighter', not higher.

Comment: @Tetsujin It is not the screen brightness if that's what you mean by brightness. The color change I see is comparable to the change I see when I play with the gamma slider in the game. It has the effect of everything being much darker and makes it much more difficult to distinguish certain darker-colored objects on the screen. I felt that the change was also similar to the change the Flux (the bedtime app) does. I'm not sure if this is gamma or some other color-setting-property (far from an expert in color settings lingo).

Comment: @JashJacob I don't know since I don't play other games

Comment: i'd be inclined to contact the developers about it. If touching the slider resets it for a moment, then it's likely in the game itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin Do you know if the macbook has some feature where it change the color pallete based on ambient light?

Comment: I've never had a laptop, but yes, 'night shift' does that - https://support.apple.com/HT207513